# How to save complex expressions in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have been debugging some long case expressions in the field calculator and getting frustrated because I have to remember to copy the expression before I test it otherwise I end up having to reenter the expression again, fix the typos, ...

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  Things like the SQL pane of the the database plugin store past queries.

Comment: I'd also like this. Sounds like a good [feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues)!